# How do I solve the following difference differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

While studying a particular physical system, I arrived at the following difference differential equation:

$$\frac{dx_n(t)}{dt} = -g \left\{\sqrt{(n + 1)(n + 2)}x_{n+1}(t) - (2n +1)x_n(t)\right\},$$

where $g$ is a constant and the initial conditions are is $x_n(0) = 0$ for $n \geq 0.$

How do I solve this?

Thank you!

---

My work:

Writing out the first equations, I got:

$$x_0'(t) = -g \{\sqrt{2}x_1(t) - x_0(t)\},$$

$$x_1'(t) = -g \{\sqrt{6}x_2(t) - 3x_1(t)\},$$

$$\vdots$$

Since these first order differential equations are interdependent, my solution to a given one of them will have to be restricted by the next  one. That's where I need your help.

Comment: Well, with $++$ in there, we don't think we understand it.

Comment: @GEdagr, it was just a plus. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe you also need an initial condition $x_0(t)$.  Then plug in to get $x_1(t)$, plug that in to get $x_2(t)$, and so on.

Comment: @GEdgar, I would be happy if that was the case, but I do not have an initial condition for all $t$ at $n = 0$. So, I would have to find the solutions for $x_1, x_2, \dots$ in terms of $x_0$ and its derivatives.

Comment: @Michael Hardy, thank you for the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $x_n(0)=0$.  Plug in $t=0$ to get $x_n'(0)=0$.  Differentiate the equation, plug in $t=0$ to get $x_n''(0)=0$, and so on: all derivatives of $x_n$ at $t=0$ are zero.

But start with any function $x_0(t)$ with all derivatives $0$ at $0$., then recursively plug in to get solutions for all the other $n$ in terms of that.  For example $x_0(t) = \exp(-1/t^2)$ with of course $x_0(0)=0$.

$$
x_{{1}} \left( t \right) ={\frac { \left( x_{{0}} \left( t
 \right) g-x'_{{0}} \left( t \right)  \right) \sqrt {2}}
{2g}}
$$

$$
x_{{2}} \left( t \right) ={\frac { 3\,x_{{0}}
 \left( t \right) {g}^{2}-4\,  x'_{{0}} \left( t
 \right)   g+x''_{{0}} \left( t \right) 
  }{{g}^{2}}}
$$

$$
x_{{3}} \left( t \right) ={\frac {15\,x_{{0}} \left( t \right) {
g}^{3}-23\, x'_{{0}} \left( t \right)   {g
}^{2}+9\, x''_{{0}} \left( t \right) 
  g-x'''_{{0}} \left( t \right) }{12{g}^{3}}}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in your example, $x_0 (0)$ is undefined. If we were given $x_0(t),$ finding the others is simple algebra. However, is there any way to find some explicit description of all possible solutions?

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I need to have $x_0$ for all time $t\geq 0$.